# How to get Variable $idc and $type From this function?

Tags: php

I create php function to call clear_url but I want to get out the variable $idc and $type, but I can't do that can anyone tell me how to do it pls?

```
function clear_url($f1,$f2,$table){     
    include('db.php');  
    $sql=$Con->query("SELECT {$f1},{$f2} FROM {$table}");

    $array=array();
    while($rowt=mysqli_fetch_object($sql)){
        $name1 = trim($rowt->$f1);
        $name1 = strtolower($name1);
        $name1 = stripslashes($name1);
        $name1 = str_replace(" ","-",$name1);
        $name1 = str_replace(".","-",$name1);
        $name1 = str_replace("  ","-",$name1);
        $name1 = str_replace("(","",$name1);
        $name1 = str_replace(")","",$name1);
        $name1 = str_replace("/","-",$name1);           
        $name1 = str_replace(",","-",$name1);
        $name1 = str_replace("'","-",$name1);                       
        $name1 = str_replace("&","-",$name1);
        $name1 = str_replace("---","-",$name1); 
        $array[]=$name1.','.$rowt->$f2;
    }
    $leng=count($array);
    for($i=0;$i<$leng;$i++){        
        $array[$i]; 

        $str=$array[$i];
        $sp=explode(",",$str);
        if($sp[0]==$_GET['name']){
            $idc=$sp[1];
            $type=$sp[0];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: hold it up to the monitor and we'll take a look

Comment: What do you mean by "get out the variable"? Do you want to return them from the function? Do you want to print them to the output? You need to be more clear.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to get the values from just one specific row in the database? Then you should use a `WHERE` clause in the SQL instead of getting all the data and looping through it.

Comment: in fact i want to do so but i don't use id to compare i used string to compare and string was change format when get from table so i need to compare it again. that's why i loop all rows.

Comment: To shorten the codes, you can combine the `str_replace()` . Read the manual for usage

Answer (score 0):

You can only return a single variable from a function; so the simplest solution to returning two values would be to put it into an array.

//EDIT - if you choose to return at a point when you haven't ensured that you've got the results; you need a conditional to actually check.

```
if (isset($type) && isset($idc)) {
    return array(
        'idc' => $idc,
        'type' => $type
    );
} else {
    return false;
}
```

and then when you call the function

```
$sample = clear_url($f1,$f2,$table);
$idc = $sample['idc'];
$type = $sample['type'];
```

Comment: I tried that but not work, it show error undefined variable TYPE.

Comment: See the edit. Of course, if you're not actually getting the `$idc` and `$type` variables, then that's another problem entirely.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins You can combine the `isset()` into one.

Comment: Really thanks for your solution now it work. Thanks so much.